# Can't install VirtualBox extension in ubuntu

Tags: wireless, usb, virtualbox

I want to install VirtualBox extension to use a wireless usb but everytime I tried to install it I got this error:

```
VBoxExtPackRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='VirtualBox version mismatch - expected 5.1 got 5.0'.


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ExtPackManagerWrap
Interface: 
IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}
```

Answer (score 1):

The VM VirtualBox Extension Pack you have tired to install does not appear to match the version of VirtualBox you are running.

5.1.2 is latest version of Virtual box

To get USB working I had to un-install and downloaded latest version and corresponding  Extension Pack.

Answer (score -1):

You must install the right VirtualBox Version for this extension like the error code displays:

```
VirtualBox version mismatch - expected 5.1 got 5.0
```

Or download the extension pack for 5.0 and install it from:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0